# Join query required in sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

i have 4 tables like below

[image]

I need the below output without using any subquery in sql server

```
PackageId  Price  ReceiptAmount
2000       1500   200
3000       800    190
```

Please any one help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: From where `PackageId` = `3000` ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47770541/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see **[ask]**.

Answer (score 1):

just use a simple join with a group by

```
SELECT
    PK.PackageId,
    Price = SUM(ISNULL(RQ.Price,0)),
    ReceiptAmount = SUM(ISNULL(RP.ReceiptAmount,0))
        FROM Package PK
            LEFT JOIN RequestDetail RQ
                ON RQ.PackageId = PK.PackageId
            LEFT JOIN Receipts RP
                ON RP.PackageId = PK.PackageId
            GROUP BY PK.PackageId
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Its working fine. But i need to include Request table also in join. I need some of the columns from the table. If i add the table the values are getting wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Hi, Its not working the Receipt amount and price are duplicated

Comment: why do you need the request table? I don't see any relevant information there

Comment: In the select query i need some information from the table. Even your first query also have the same issues.

Comment: so that means there are more columns in your actual table than the one you have given above? if so, please give the complete design or add more detail to the question